# How to update config file of prometheus if it is running as service on mac?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

How to update prometheus.yml file of prometheus if it is running as service on mac?
Please share the command to update prometheus prometheus.yml file on mac.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you installed prometheus with brew, and run with `brew services start prometheus`
you can edit the config file which in `/usr/local/etc/prometheus.yml`,then you can restart prometheus with command `brew services restart prometheus`

Answer (score 7):

My config file was in a different directory for me: `/opt/homebrew/etc/prometheus.yml`

There was some helper text after the install that args are set here `/opt/homebrew/etc/prometheus.args`.

The args had a key for where the config file lived:

```
--config.file /opt/homebrew/etc/prometheus.yml
--web.listen-address=127.0.0.1:9090
--storage.tsdb.path /opt/homebrew/var/prometheus
```

Comment: Mine's in `/opt/homebrew...` too

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find it by myself as well, finally I found it in `/opt/homebrew/etc/prometheus.yml`. But I don't think this is a good way to find it by looping the possible file paths mentioned above as different conventions might be applied.

I suggested to check the `http://localhost:9090/flags` directly(if you deployed in another ip:port in your local, replace it please). Then you will see all flags used to start, then you can try to find the `--config.file` flag which shows you the configuration file it uses.

[image]